# Unable to write a generic function that can work on multiple Structs in Golang

Tags: go, refactoring, go-interface, go-structtag

I am new to Go, and learning Interfaces and Structs. I am having 2 structs - *ServiceSection* and *SliderSection* and I am trying to accomplish the below 2 tasks with each of them-

1. GET the JSON response and unmarshal it.
2. Use the struct to create HTML using *"html/template"*

Therefore, I am trying to create a common function to perform both the tasks that can work for multiple Structs. The plan is to create 5-6 more such structs. Below is the code I have created-

```
package main
import (
            "bytes"
            "encoding/json"
            "fmt"
            "io/ioutil"
            "log"
            "net/http"
            "html/template"
        )
        
        const (
            getServicesAPI = "https://huyk1a44n6.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/services"
            getSliderAPI   = "https://huyk1a44n6.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/home-slider"
        
            servicesTemplate = `<div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="section-title">
                            <h5>{{.Heading1}}</h5>
                            <h2>{{.Heading2}}</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  
                   {{range .Services}}
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                        <a class="single-services-box" href="{{.Href}}">
                            <div class="services-img">
                                <img alt="Service Images"
                                     src="{{.Image}}">
                            </div>
                            <h3>{{.Heading}}</h3>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    {{end}}
        
                </div>
            </div>`
        
            sliderTemplate = `    {{range .Slider}}
            <div class="home-slider flickity-dots-absolute" data-flickity='{ "bgLazyLoad": 1, "bgLazyLoad": true, "fade": true, "prevNextButtons": false, "autoPlay": 7000, "pauseAutoPlayOnHover": false }'>
                <div class="home-slider-single-item" data-flickity-bg-lazyload="{{.Image}}">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row d-flex align-items-center">
                            <div class="col">
                                <div class="home-slider-content">
                                    <h1 class="home-slider-title">{{.title}}</h1>
                                    <div class="home-slider-description">
                                        <p>{{.description}}</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="home-slider-btn-box">
                                        <a class="button home-btn-1 mr-15" href="{{.button1_href}}">{{.button1_title}}</a>
                                        <a class="button btn-primary" href="{{.button2_href}}">{{.button1_title}}</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {{end}}
        `
        )
        
        type ServiceSection struct {
            Heading1 string `json:"Heading1"`
            Heading2 string `json:"Heading2"`
            Services []struct {
                Image   string `json:"Image"`
                Href    string `json:"Href"`
                Heading string `json:"Heading"`
            } `json:"Services"`
        }
        
        type SliderStruct struct {
            Title        string `json:"title"`
            Description  string `json:"description"`
            Button1Title string `json:"button1_title"`
            Button1Href  string `json:"button1_href"`
            Button2Title string `json:"button2_title"`
            Button2Href  string `json:"button2_href"`
            Image        string `json:"Image"`
        }
        
        type SliderSection struct {
            Slider []SliderStruct
        }
        
        type MyInterface interface {
            populateHTML(string, string)
        }
        
        func (ss ServiceSection) populateHTML(endpoint string, tmpl string) {
            populateHTMLcommon(ss, endpoint, tmpl)
        }
        func (ss SliderSection) populateHTML(endpoint string, tmpl string) {
            populateHTMLcommon(ss, endpoint, tmpl)
        }
        
        func main() {
            println("WASM Go Initialized")
        
            ServiceSec := ServiceSection{}
            SliderSec := SliderSection{}
        
            ServiceSec.populateHTML(getServicesAPI, servicesTemplate)
            SliderSec.populateHTML(getSliderAPI, sliderTemplate)
        
        }
        
        func populateHTMLcommon(hs MyInterface, endpoint string, tmplStr string) {
            fmt.Println("struct ServiceSection", hs, endpoint)
        
            // GET API CALL
            fmt.Println("Inside getDataFromAPI()")
        
            response, err := http.Get(endpoint)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
        
            responseData, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
        
            err = json.Unmarshal(responseData, &hs)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
        
            // Create HTML using template
            tmpl := template.Must(template.New("table").Parse(tmplStr))
        
            buf := new(bytes.Buffer)              // Buffer created to hold the final HTML
            err = tmpl.Execute(buf, responseData) // Populate the data in the HTML template
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
        
            tableHTMLString := buf.String()
            fmt.Println("tableHTMLString: ", tableHTMLString)
        }
```

On executing the above program I am getting the below error in the ***populateHTMLcommon()*** function while unmarshaling the JSON -

> json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type main.MyInterface

This means it's not able to identify the appropriate struct from the ***MyInterface*** interface.

I don't understand how I can create a common function that could work for multiple structs. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you come up with a _minimal_ example of what you want to do? Note that it is impossible to write truly generic functions and very hard and cumbersome to write almost generic functions using reflection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things:

- A Go interface is an abstraction - so it's rare, if ever, that you need to get the address of an interface
- if a struct's method needs to change the state of the struct (and persist the change), use a pointer receiver.

So to fix your immediate problems:

```
// err = json.Unmarshal(responseData, &hs) // address of an interface usually is not what you want
err = json.Unmarshal(responseData, hs)
```

and update your method signatures to use pointer-receivers:

```
func (ss *ServiceSection) populateHTML(endpoint string, tmpl string) {
    populateHTMLcommon(ss, endpoint, tmpl)
}
func (ss *SliderSection) populateHTML(endpoint string, tmpl string) {
    populateHTMLcommon(ss, endpoint, tmpl)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/cGmm3Cs5XTk